# How to view SQL Server CE system tables in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce-4

I can open a SQL Server CE 4.0 `.sdf` file in Visual Studio 2012 and it appears in the Server Explorer. All good.

But as far as I can tell it only shows the regular tables, not system tables.

Is there a way to show system tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in order to see them, you must type for example:

```
SELECT *  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Which also means you must know the name in advance (the command above lists all available tables by the way)